# Road network data with speed limits

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe

I need road network data of Sweden with the speed limit of each segment of the road. I downloaded it from https://download.geofabrik.de/ but unfortunately, there are a lot of missing values there. Is there any other website to get this data from?

Comment: Cross posting is frowned upon: choose an SE site and post your question there. If you want to switch SE's, close your question on one site and open it on another. For others stumbling on this question: the OP has posed the same question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/379060/162234) and received some answers.